# Secure Configurable Product Page, But Returns, non-secure ajax response and is blocked

Tags: configurable-product, ajax, https, prototype-js

Okay guys, I am a bit baffled. 
I am loading a configurable product’s page using a secure connection (https://) and I select all the variables, which sends the ajax call, but its returning with an http:// connection and is blocking it due to mixed content.

The prototype.js file, that is calling the ajax function is loaded as securely… so why is it returning a non-secure url for the ajax call?
Any help would be awesome.
For reference:

```
  this.transport.open(this.method.toUpperCase(), this.url,
```

line 1521: in the prototype.js file. Magento 1.9.1